# Installing odfWeave gets hung up on "checking for xml2-config..."

Tags: r

I can't install odfWeave - it looks like the problem is with the package XML, which gets as far as "checking for xml2-config..." and then cannot find it. :

```
checking for xml2-config... no Cannot find xml2-config 
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’
* removing ‘/home/andreas/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.10/XML’
* installing *source* package ‘odfWeave’ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading Warning in library(pkg, character.only
= TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc) :   there is no package called 'XML' Error : package 'XML'
could not be loaded ERROR: lazy
loading failed for package ‘odfWeave’
* removing ‘/home/andreas/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.10/odfWeave’
```

Comment: Learn about 'apt-cache searn r-cran-'. Many packages you may want are there, but of course not all 2200+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better still:   `sudo apt-get install r-cran-xml`

Comment: Thank you both! I am now a happy camper. - Is it always recommended to use apt-get instead of install.packages()?

Comment: No, it's more complicated as Ubuntu may lag in time (as the release freezes).  This gets discussed on r-sig-debian (also for Ubuntu) from time to time -- look there.   But if the other approach fails, it is always better ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

it should work after that...

Comment: See my answer about `apt-get install r-cran-xml` which should be easier for most users.

Comment: What's the catch? I have had problems with installing `XML` R package and managed to install it after installing `libxml2-dev` package. `odfWeave` depends on `XML` package... and now I installed `r-cran-xml`... so is it some kind of metapackage, or what? What's the difference between `r-cran-xml` and R `XML` package?

Comment: The `XML` package must be built from source and so needs to find an XML parsing library to link against- in this case libxml2.  The development headers must be installed for the compiler to perform the link, hence the need for `libxml2-dev`.  `r-cran-xml` is distributed as a precompiled Debian binary, so no compiling needs to take place.  The only difference is that the version of `XML` provided by `r-cran-xml` may lag behind what you could get by building `XML` from source.