# installing odfWeave to R in an offline environment

Tags: r, package

as title, I want to try odfWeave, but the network in my office is so restricted that I can't access the repos outside, is there anything I can do to install the odfWeave package?

Thanks!

P.S. I am using R-portable 2.11.0, I have tried Rtools but it prompt me with an error of package XML not found, which is not true

Comment: Please add for which platform and if possible give a bit more info on _which_ package XML you have installed. Given you mention Rtools the platform would be windows. related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501369/help-installing-odfweave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure that you have the correct package XML installed, and you're absolutely sure it's installed correctly, then you can just download the source of the odfWeave package and install from there. You don't need Rtools for that, just do :

```
install.packages(
    c("path/to/file/odfWeave_x.x.xx.tar.gz",
    repos = NULL,
    type="source"
)
```

If / when it becomes available, you could install from the downloaded binary for windows, but then you have to set `type` to "win.binary" or "win64.binary" depending on the version you have.

Comment: I don't think there is currently a Windows binary available on CRAN. I was able to download the source yesterday and install w/ no problems on Windows 7, 64 bit running R 2.12 as you suggested above. See [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odfWeave/index.html) and click on the ReadMe for the Windows binary for more info.

Comment: no worries, I just happened to have spent 20 minutes yesterday banging my head into the wall trying to figure that out!